# Merged DataTable Don't Copy To New Form

Tags: datatable

f I have 2 DataTables (dt1 and dt4) and I want to merge them and put them in another (dtFinal). How can I do this in vb.net?
 I tried the Merge statement on the datatable, but the Problem it get the columns but not the value from the table

dt1 > Is manually written dt

dt4 > is Excel File loaded to dt

I Need to merge them to the new Form and them make Sum on the two qty Column
to get as image attached , but all working
[Merged Two Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJdju.jpg)

```
     Dim dtFinal As New DataTable
        dtFinal = Frm_DiffLive.dt4.Copy
        dtFinal.Merge(Frm_DiffLive.dt)
        dtFinal.Merge(Frm_DiffLive.dt4)
        Me.dgvFinal.DataSource = dtFinal
```

1- It Load All Columns From Two dataTAble
But Only Contents of DataTable Fills Manually
Not The One That Populated From Excel File ???

Do I Need To save it first to memory or something like that ?

2- how to make one column from the new dtFinal is the sum between Two column at each Row ??
f

I have tried a lot of merge lines , but i think as the columns appear correct, it's not merge problem

Answer (score 0):

The beat solution was to save the two table to db first 
Thene re- select it again anf do the whole required process.